# Reference previous rows in Dataframe calculations (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do a calculation where I add a new DataFrame column that calculates the average of the previous 2 values. Here is the desired outcome:

```
    Input    Prev. 2 Avg
0   2        NaN
1   2        NaN
2   3        2.0
3   3        2.5
4   4        3.0
5   4        3.5
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to reference the previous rows for the calculation. It works if I add two additional columns, one being the Input shifted 1, the other shifted 2. Then I can do the calculation across:

```
 df["Input1"] = df["Input"].shift(1)

df["Input2"] = df["Input"].shift(2)

df["Prev. 2 Avg"] = (df["Input1"] + df["Input2"])/2
```

This just feels clunky and awkward, plus I am creating two new (unnecessary) columns.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Prev. 2 Avg'] = df.Input.rolling(2).mean().shift()
```